# Making a button activated image scroller into an automated scroller

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wanting to make a automatic image scroller, but it is currently button activated. I am currently stuck on how I would make it into an automatic timed image scroller while still having the buttons.

The live demo is available on my site: [here](http://harrisonbh.com/dev/transitions/).

From there it would be easiest just to view the source code, it is a little too much to put on jsFiddle.

I belive that I need to put something along the lines of:

`window.setInterval(function(){navigate( ‘next’ )}, 1000);`

in my `main.js` file after one of the `isAnimating = false;` instances.

Although, that doesn't seem to be working for me. I have tried just about anything, but I'm not sure. In order to help people who will see this in the future with similar or slightly similar problems, please also answer with ideas on how to do this to all button activated events.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is how i have done it in the past

```
<body>
<img id=img1>
<button id="btn1">
<button id="btn2">

<script>
var timeout = setTimeout(new function() {changeImg("next");}, someTime); 
btn1.onclick = function ()
{
    changeImg("next");
    return false;
}
btn2.onclick = function ()
{
    changeImg("prev");
    return false;
}
changeImg(direction)
{
     clearTimeout(timeout)
     timeout = setTimeout(new function() {changeImg("next");}, someTime); 
     //Do Work - change img1.src
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in relationship to my code, where would this be implemented and how?

Comment: it would be placed in the jscript of the page where you are trying to implement the effect - it does not go in a separate code file

Comment: How exactly would I get that to work with my code? Did you look at my code? It doesn't use any buttons.

Comment: Is this honestly what stack overflow has come to?